# Make a matrix with input inside a DIV by mixing input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="a">
       <input value="1" />
       <input value="2" />
       <input value="3" />
    </div> 
    <div id="b">
      <input value="4" />
      <input value="5" />
    </div> 
</div>
```

I need to get each input value inside `div#a` and each input value in `div#b` and build a matrix/mixing of those values, taking the same example as before, this is what the code should return:

```
<div id="mixed">
    <input value="1" /><input value="4" />
    <input value="1" /><input value="5" />

    <input value="2" /><input value="4" />
    <input value="2" /><input value="5" />

    <input value="3" /><input value="4" />
    <input value="3" /><input value="5" />
</div>
```

I have tried to move inside `div#main` using this code:

```
    $("#main div").each(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        console.log("that.attr('id')");
    });
```

But `console.log()` never logs something so I must doing something wrong. This is a advanced topic for me and need some help, any?

**UPDATE**

At this point I have this maded:

```
$("#choices div").each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.each(function() {
        var thati = $(this);
        console.log(thati);
    });
});
```

And I think in the second `.each()` is where I can get the input values and try to build the matrix

Comment: You are logging a string, not a code result.

Comment: What is the reason of doing that?

Comment: @undefined I just trying to get what I have in each loop to then try to mix the values

Comment: @Diodeus it logs the string now I forgot something on my code (non related to this) now the problem is how to create the matrix as I said before

Comment: You must concatenate the different parts of your string (operator +).

Comment: @Frederik.L you're right I just don't get how to do it

Comment: It is the only scenerio? or could you have matrices of other order as well? if its the latter then I guess the only way to acheive it is to crack open a mathematics book, understand the basics of matrices and then apply it to solve the problem.

Comment: @user1 not is not, this is just a example but DIV can grow up lets say today are only a and b but tomorrow could be a, b, c, d ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should help:

```
var arr = [];
$('#a input').each(function () {
  var that = $(this);
  $('#b input').each(function () {
    arr.push(that.val());
    arr.push($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Then go through the array and dynamically generate the HTML. You can treat this like a matrix by stepping every 2 values.

Comment: I'm trying with this code based on yours but `arr` is empty: var `arr = [];

        $("#choices div").each(function() {
            var that = $(this);

            that.each(function() {
                arr.push(that.val());
                arr.push($(this).val());
            });
        });
        
        console.log(arr);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $('#a input');
var b = $('#b input');
var html = '';
a.each(function () {
    var first = this;
    b.each(function () {
        html += '<div>' + first.outerHTML + this.outerHTML + '</div>'
    });
});

$('#mix').html(html);
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/At2d9/1/)

update: code for what's asked for in comments.

```
var divs = $('#main > div');

var html = '';
divs.each(function (index) {
    var divsLength = divs.length,
        inputs = $('input', divs[index]),
        inputsLength = inputs.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < divsLength; i++) {
        if (i === index) {
            continue;
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < inputsLength; j++) {
            $('input', divs[i]).each(function () {
                html += inputs[j].outerHTML + this.outerHTML + '<br />';
            });
        }
    }
});

$('#mix').html(html);
```

Comment: This is almost what I get but something is missing, right now I have only to children div **a** and **b** but what happens when I got three or more since they are created on the fly? I need to build the function as general as possible to use in any case